# Joomla and JoomlaFCK Editor

Tags: editor, joomla

I have Joomla site and default front end editor JoomlaFCK (now it's new version JoomlaCK editor). When some member (they are all Author type of user) try to write some article, he can write it, but can't publish it, so I have to publish it from the back end. I check all Joomla options, but not found anything. I know it's simple, maybe right in front of me, but it's very annoying for me. Help. TIA.

P.S.  If there is some better editor, I can think of change.

Regards

DZvonko

Answer (score 0):

By default, an author will not have permission to publish the item. They would need to be a publisher. Look at the user information in Users and change their group.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to give them lot of permissions. Also, older versions had possibilities for publishing items on front-end, but they are complaining about their "age". "Please upgrade" with every access.